# Sympy extract Fourier Series coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I am using `sympy` to carry on some symbolic math manipulations.

Start by creating a Fourier series representation of a rectangular pulse train (duty cycle < 50%), then try to access the multiplying factors, i.e. `a_n` and `b_n` of the standard Fourier series.

In a nutshell:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import fourier_series, pi, cos, sin
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy.functions.special.delta_functions import Heaviside
T = sy.symbols('T')
s = fourier_series(Heaviside(t) - Heaviside(t-1/4), (t, 0, 1))
s.truncate(3)

1/π*sin(2πt)+1/π*sin(4πt)+1/π*cos(2πt)+0.25
```

I would then like to access the coefficients of the base functions. To this extent, I thought I should use `as_coefficient(expr)`.

This produces the expected results in a simpler case:

```
g = 1/(pi*T)*sin(2*pi*t)
g.as_coefficient(sin(2*pi*t))

1/πT
```

However, with the object returned by `fourier_series`, this does not seem to work:

```
a = s.truncate(3)
a.as_coefficient(sin(2*pi*t))
```

returns nothing (not even a warning or message).

Other methods like `s.as_Add()` or `s.as_Mul()` return both a full expression where the `a_n` is tied to its `sin(2*pi*n*t)` term (or `b_n` to its dual).

Comment: Referring to the code in the question, what is "sy" in sy.symbols('T') ?

Comment: There was an ``import sympy as sy`` implied. I've now edited the original post for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `as_coefficient` can't handle a sum of terms like `2*sin(x)+3*cos(x)`: it picks the coefficient only if the given expression (like `sin(x)`) can be factored out. So, in order to use it you need to separate the series into chunks with one trig function each. This can be done, but it's easier to change the approach:

1. Use `s.truncate(None)` to get a generator for the series.
2. For each term produced by the generator, plug 0 to get cosine coefficient, and plug 1/(4*k) of the interval length to get sine coefficient (here k is the index)

The reason this works: at 0, sine is 0 and cosine is 1; at 1/4 of length, cosine is 0 and sine is 1.

[image: trig]

---

```
from sympy import fourier_series, pi, cos, sin
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy.functions.special.delta_functions import Heaviside
s = fourier_series(Heaviside(t) - Heaviside(t-1/4), (t, 0, 1))
iter = s.truncate(None)
cosine_coeffs = []
sine_coeffs = [0]       # there is no sine term for k = 0
for k in range(0, 4):
    term = next(iter)
    cosine_coeffs.append(term.subs(t, 0))
    if k > 0:
        sine_coeffs.append(term.subs(t, 1/(4*k)))
```

Result:

```
 cosine_coeffs = [0.250000000000000, 1/pi, 0, -1/(3*pi)]

 sine_coeffs = [0, 1/pi, 1/pi, 1/(3*pi)]
```

Comment: Wow that looks cool!
There are few things I need to chew, first one being the iterator concept which I used very seldom.
I got to a partial conclusion that to get my coefficients I should go 'one level deeper' and say: `a = s.truncate(3); m = a.args[1]; m.as_coeff_mul[1][0]` to finally get my factor...Which as you pointed out is cumbersome and I could not really find an automated way of doing it for the general case.
Maybe after understanding iterators I'll give it a second chance, for the learning effect ;)

Answer (score 4):

The class `sympy.series.fourier.FourierSeries` has methods to provide  `sympy.series.sequences.sequence` objects with the cosine and sine terms of the series: `a0`, `an` and `bn`.

After computing the series by

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy import fourier_series
from sympy.abc import t
from sympy.functions.special.delta_functions import Heaviside
s = fourier_series(Heaviside(t) - Heaviside(t-1/4), (t, 0, 1))
```

The cosine coefficients can be obtained by

```py
s.a0
```

```
0.25
```

and

```py
s.an
```

[image: a_n cosine coefficients].

For the sine coefficients

```py
s.bn
```

[image: b_n sine coefficients].

So in order to produce lists of the `s` series coefficients up to a given order, let say 4 that can be done with

```py
def cosine_fourier_coeffs(fourierSeries, order):
    ### returns a list of fourier series cosine coefficients up to order
    out = []
    out.append(fourierSeries.a0)
    for i in range(1,order):
        out.append(fourierSeries.an.coeff(i).subs(t, 0 ) )
    return out

def sine_fourier_coeffs(fourierSeries, order):
    ### returns a list of fourier series sine coefficients up to order
    out = []
    for i in range(1,order):
        out.append(fourierSeries.bn.coeff(i).subs(t, 1/(4* i) ) )
    return out

cosine_fourier_coeffs(s, 4), sine_fourier_coeffs(s, 4)
```

that will return

```
([0.250000000000000, 1/pi, 0, -1/(3*pi)], [1/pi, 1/pi, 1/(3*pi)])
```